# ec2 load balancer determine which instance got request

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I have a couple of ec2 instances sitting behind a load balancer. How can I determine which requests went to a particular instance?

Is there a log? Somewhere on the console I can look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know of an direct way on the console. You could either activate ELB access logs and look at the backend:port field in the logs which gives the instaces ip ([docs here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/access-log-collection.html)). Or you could have your application running on your instances add something to the headers to identify themselves in their responses.